# having issues to launch swagger-ui.html - jersey2 swagger-ui using jaxrs using non-xml way with swagger.json on context root level

Tags: jersey-2.0, swagger-ui

I have swagger.json generated using java code and used maven. I have downloaded the static files and placed inside WEB-INF folder, however I cannot access the swagger-ui.html/ index.html

Thanks in advance.

```
        <dependency>
          <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
          <artifactId>swagger-jersey2-jaxrs</artifactId>
          <version>1.5.13</version>
          <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
                <artifactId>jsr311-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
          </exclusions>
        </dependency>


    ServletRegistration.Dynamic swaggerServlet = servletContext.addServlet("Jersey2Config", new JerseyJaxrsConfig());
    swaggerServlet.setInitParameter("api.version", "1.0.0");
    swaggerServlet.setInitParameter("swagger.api.basepath","/");
    swaggerServlet.setLoadOnStartup(2);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out that this is a conflict with default servlet and my rest servlet,

so i changed my service to go under /service/*

and then now i can access static swagger-ui.html and feed the swagger.json to get my swagger-ui.html working..